# How to fill in 4 different ArrayLists from one text file?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am programming a simple quiz with questions and answers und would like to make 4 ArrayLists for 4 categories of questions. The user is supposed to choose  one category and to answer 10 random questions from ArrayList. 
I found a piece of code with one ArrayList without categories. I have no idea how to implement 4 ArrayLists and to fill them in from one text file. Could someone help me please?

```
public class Questions {

private ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

public Questions()  {
    try {
        File f = new File("src/main/resources/questions.txt");
        FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);

        String line;
        String question = "";
        String[] alternatives = null;

        int answer = 0;

        int numberOfAlternatives = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        do {

            do {
                line = scanner.nextLine();

                if (line.contains("?")) { //stores the question
                    question = line;
                } else if(counter == 0 && line.length() == 1) { //stores the number of alternatives
                    numberOfAlternatives = Integer.valueOf(line);
                    alternatives = new String[numberOfAlternatives];
                } else if (line.contains(")")) { //stores the alternatives
                    alternatives[counter++] = line;
                } else if (Character.isDigit(line.indexOf(0)) || counter == numberOfAlternatives) { //Stores the answer
                    answer = Integer.valueOf(line);
                }

            }   while (answer == 0);

            questions.add(new Question(question, alternatives, answer));
            numberOfAlternatives = 0;
            counter = 0;
            answer = 0;

        }   while (scanner.hasNext());


        r.close();
        reader.close();
        scanner.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public ArrayList<Question> getQuestions()  {
    return questions;
}
```

}

Comment: Create a class structure that matches your domain and parse your data into that. From what I read you have `Quiz` --> `Category`+ --> `Question`+ --> `Answer`+.

Comment: you can simply use a file `questions-cat_one.txt`, `questions-cat_two.txt`  , etc for every category. use a while and read every category file and create an `ArrayList` for every file

Comment: Now I have a Quiz class containing the  main- method , a Question class with a constructor for objects of type Question and a class Questions which I've just posted here.  In the constructor I have 3 attirbutes - String question, String[] alternatives, int correctAnswer.

Comment: 4 files instead of 1? I heard that it is not the best way to solve the problem....

Comment: if you want one file for all categories you can use a separator in your file for example %%category_name%% and separate questions in categories this way.for example you have this separator in first line of file then 10 question then a new separator for next category then 20 questions,...  but your questions could not have this separator in question body (here %%) when you reach this you can use category name and then change `arrayList`.